# Cannot compile Twitter Bootstrap core and responsive into one file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, import, responsive-design, less

We have an override file for twitter bootstrap,

It begins with

```
@import "../less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../less/responsive.less";
```

The issue with this is that, when both the `bootstrap.less` and `responsive.less` are imported into one file we end up with the grid not lining up, basically it totals over 100% causing the items to float onto the next line.

If we don't import them together, and just import the `bootstrap.less` and then do another file with `responsive.less` it works fine.

What's up with that?

Bootstrap 2.3.1
Compiler: lessPHP 0.3.9 (2.3.1 compatible)

Is there any way around this, or must I use two separate files?

Answer (score 2):

Add repsonsive.less to the end of your bootstrap.less file. Like this:

```
...
// Utility classes
@import "utilities.less"; // Has to be last to override when necessary
@import "responsive.less"; //
```